# Error importing javax.jnlp libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, import, libraries, jnlp

I'm using a book as a guide to do it but it doesn't tell anything about this issue.

I am trying to import this 3 things on Java Eclipse.

```
import javax.jnlp.FileContents;
import javax.jnlp.FileOpenService;
import javax.jnlp.ServiceManager;
```

And the following error message that i get is this:

[image]

To be more specific I'm trying to run an application that extends JApplet and requires the following things to get work. I'm on Lessons that i learn about xml files etc. So i don't really know a lot of them. Just started out.  I heard that i need to download some JAR files or new JDK and some Java Demo Samples. but i have no idea what to do first and if this is what i need to do.

So, can someone excplains me what that error is and how to do it step by step? **Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot of research about that i finally found it how to do it.

The missing libraries that i was looking for, there are on javaws.jar file that was on the location below:

```
Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\javaws.jar
```

The javaws.jar file includes all **jnlp** libraries that you need to.

**To simply put this on Eclipse you need to do the following steps:**

1) On Eclipse click on Project then click on Properties.

2) Go to Java Build Path and select libraries from the Tabs.

3) Click on Add External JARs...

4) Enter the Location of the file "javaws.jar".

5) Apply and Ok.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your JDK is already working, you don't have to install another one.

You should download the missing library (.jar) and than include it to the project libraries, which can be accessed through the build path.